# How to draw the best fitting line on Hooke's Model for a spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, data-analysis

I just started learning about Hooke's Law and calculating the slope of a force vs. extension graph of a spring for the spring constant. If I conduct an experiment and the extension length of my spring isn't accurately proportional to the force on the spring, how should I go about plotting the graph, and how do I find the slope and spring constant of that graph? Should I ignore the odd points on the graph in order to form a straight line?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how bad your results were. But if you can see that the points are scattered around a line you must use a [Linear Regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression). If they don't, then you messed really bad, you must redo your experiment.

Using Linear Regression you can calculate the parameters (slope and y-intercept) of the best fitting line ($y = ax + b$), and it's uncertainties. But a quick and not so precise way of measuring the slope is to drawn a line that kinda of fits between your data. This [page](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit-eyeball-method) will give more details on how to do it.

But keep in mind that Hooke's law is only a first-order linear approximation to the real response of springs and other elastic bodies to applied forces. It must eventually fail once the forces exceed some limit, since no material can be compressed beyond a certain minimum size, or stretched beyond a maximum size, without some permanent deformation or change of state. Many materials will noticeably deviate from Hooke's law well before those elastic limits are reached.

About the experiment itself: No matter how accurate or precise your measurements are, your F v. $\Delta x$ plot will never be a PERFECT line. There will always be some uncertainty (intrinsic to the physical system or uncertainty on the measurement). By use of Error Propagation you can propagate those error into your calculation of the spring constant (those famous error bars and confidence intervals).

Answer (score 1):

Hooke's Law assumes an ideal spring.  Many real springs have "pre-compression" built into them, and those springs require some amount of force before they show any extension.  This means that the points on your graph of force vs. extension will not fall strictly on a straight line.

To create your graph, draw the best straight line through your data points.  The best straight line is the line that comes closest to all the points, and that line may or may not pass through any one point in your data set.  From that line, determine your equation of $y = mx + b$, where $m$ corresponds to the spring constant.