# What factors does a Spring depend on?

Tags: experimental-physics, spring, elasticity, approximations, continuum-mechanics

When we consider an ideal spring, the force applied by the spring is proportional to its extension $f_{sp} = kx$. Does the same apply in real life?

So I took it into my own hands. I got a spring similar to this (the longer one)
[image]

I had a bunch of 50gram weights which can be hooked to one another and I was able to rigidly fix one end of the spring and hang it. now I slowly added the weights and calculated the deviations and the extensions were nowhere close to linear(50g->5cm, 100g->14cm).

I checked accurately that the masses had an average of less than a 2 gram error from 50g. I Also rigidly fixed a scale and am pretty sure it was fixed rigidly and I took proper readings with minimal errors.

I tried taking proper $g$ values, accommodating for small errors and nothing seemed to explain these odd readings. I also checked with a different tighter and smaller spring which again proved $f_{sp} = kx$ wrong.

Is there some term that we are neglecting while calculating $f_{sp}$ to make the calculations easier?

Comment: If your springs look like the ones in the picture I have found that sometimes there is a range of small forces that result in no measurable extension.  Once the coils of the spring start to separate then it seems to obey Hooke's Law more closely.  Is that the sort of issue that you are running into?

Comment: not exactly. even after a third weight is added, it is still very much disproportionate

Comment: It would really, really help for you to graph your data and show us. I can think of a couple of possibilities for what's happening, but without seeing the data I have no idea which is correct. Or at least describe it. Does your data look like F = kx but with tons of noise? Does it look like F = kx + c? Does it look like F = -ax^2 + bx? Does it look completely random?

Comment: Yes, we need more than two data points to make any suggestions.

Comment: *"even after a third weight is added, it is still very much disproportionate"* Try smaller weights. Hooke's law only holds in general for small displacements about equilibrium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more data it is hard to say much, but one issue may be that springs such as those shown in the image are often pre-compressed with an [initial tension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f5aQ9eHCcE) ($T_0$) that needs to be overcome before the spring starts extending. For example, see the "Initial Tension" listed by the manufacturer for [these springs](https://www.coilspringsdirect.com/store/entex-tension-springs). For an ideal pre-compressed spring, this still produces a linear (~ Hooke's Law) relation between extension $x$ and load $L$, but with a zero offset, i.e.
$$x = \mathrm{Max}[(L-T_0)/k,\,0]$$

["How to draw the best fitting line on Hooke's Model for a spring?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/612653/145491) may also be helpful.

Comment: This explained stuff pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

> When we consider an ideal spring, the force applied by the spring is proportional to its extension $f_{sp} = kx$. Does the same apply in real life?

No, it does not apply exactly in real life, since there are no ideal springs in real life.

However, for *small* displacements about *some* equilibrium positions the law will hold.

> 

> Is there some term that we are neglecting while calculating $f_{sp}$ to make the calculations easier?

Yes, you are neglecting certain aspects of the real physical spring. As we can see in the picture, the physical spring is made up of coils of a finite thickness, and when those metal coils are compressed together so that they touch each other they can not be compress any further without great effort.

So, your spring will fail to be ideal at least in the compression direction. In other words, instead of looking like a parabolic potential it will look like half a parabola and then a very sharp jump when the metal starts to contact other metal.

If you want to see the region where the spring acts approximately ideally, you should pre-stretch the spring by hanging a little weight off of it and then observe small oscillations of the weight about its equilibrium position.